# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-service, iife

I have create a project MVC in the layout i have this (for load Menu Categories):

```html
<html data-ng-app="app">
.
.
.
//in the menu
<li class="dropdown" ng-controller="menuCategoriesCtrl as vmCat">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Categorias<span class="caret"></span> 
  </a>
  <ul id="listaCategorias" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-repeat="categoria in vmCat.categories">
    <li>
      <a ng-href="{{categoria.url}}">
        {{categoria.Nombre}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
```

the app.js is this:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']).config(configRoute);

    configRoute.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    function configRoute($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/Home.html',
                controller: 'productosPrincipalCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/Mapa', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/Map.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); //.hashPrefix("!")
    }

})();
```

the controller for the menu Categories is this:

```js
(function() {

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('menuCategoriesCtrl', menuCategoriesCtrl);

    menuCategoriesCtrl.$inject = ['categoryService'];

    function menuCategoriesCtrl(categoryService) {

        var vmCategory = this;
        var listCat = [];

        vmCategory.listCategories = [];

        getListCategories().then(function() {

            for (var i = 0; i < listCat.length; i++) {
                vmCategory.listCategories.push({
                    url: '#/Categoria/' + listCat.CategoriaId + '-' + listCat.Nombre,
                    nombreCategoria: listCat.Nombre
                });
            }

        });

        function getListCategories() {
            return categoryService.getCategories()
                .then(function(response) {
                    listCat = response;
                    return listCat;
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    return alert('Error ' + response);
                });
        };

    }

})();
```

and the service is this:

```js
(function() {

    var uriCategorias = 'http://localhost/Api/GetCategories';

    angular.module('app')
        .service('categoryService', categoryService);

    categoryService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function categoryService($http) {

        var srvCat = this;

        srvCat.getCategories = getCategories;

        function getCategories() {

            return $http.get(uriCategorias)
                .then(getCategoriesComplete)
                .cath(getCategoriesFail);

            function getCategoriesComplete(response) {
                return response.data;
            }

            function getCategoriesFail(response) {
                return alert('Error ' + response);
            }
        }

    }
})
```

when i execute this in the browser i have a error for the inject in controller in the service.

Can somebody explain me why?

the name is correct i have reference all in the bundle in the app_start

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the service function, as you are using Self Executing function(IIFE pattern). Because the function of service.js not called, it doesn't bind the `service` component to `app` module. Hence injecting service in your code giving error as its not registered with app module.

**Code**

```
(function() {

    //service code as is

})(); <-- () self calling function should be there
```